# Saving the content of the src attribute in the localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am developping an online os
And i want to save the application icons in the localstorage but i don't know how i should save the content of the src attribute in the localstorage and read it out again on the apps page. my current code results in a blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you simply trying to save the source URL?  Or the image content?

You can save source URL by something like the following:

```
var theImage = document.getElementById('my-special-image');
if (window.localStorage) {
     window.localStorage['theImage_src'] = theImage.src;
}
```

If you want to save the contents of the image, then you have to do some fiddling around with canvas, using
`canvas.toDataURL()`.   See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) for more info on how to do that.

Comment: Also, you may want to look into CSS sprites, by the sound of your question.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to do it. Everything you could save to local storage must be referenced by a variable. And the value would be converted into string format when call localStorage.setItem method.

```
localStorage.setItem('my', {a: 1});

console.log(localStorage['my']); // you will get a string value: '[object Object]'
```

Comment: Actually you can save objects by JSON encoding them.  Several browsers support `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.  I believe this is native to IE8, Opera 10.50, Firefox 3.5, Safari 4.0.3 and Chrome.  There are also various libraries around to provide this if it's not native to the browser.  See also [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: What i mean is that everything you set to localstorage will be converted to string format. Of course you can stringify an object to string format if you will.

Answer (score 0):

Are the icons user supplied or your own? In either case, convert your application icons to base64. Then stick it into localStorage. Of course you'll have to stringify the data to store.

```
var base64 = localStorage.getItem('icon_name');
$('#imgid').attr('src', base64);
```